# Google app engine - How can i run the server as HTTPS for python?

Tags: google-app-engine, web, https

While running Google App Engine it is possible to run as http, but how do i run it as https?

```
$ python2.7 /var/tmp/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host 0.0.0.0 /var/tmp/app
INFO     2013-08-20 21:21:21,093 dispatcher.py:164] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2013-08-20 21:21:21,099 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

EDIT:

Step 1:

```
I purchased a.crt and a.key from a service provider such as heart internet from UK.
```

Step 2: i place the a.crt and a.key file with contents

```
sun@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp/private$ ls
a.crt  a.key
sun@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp/private$ cat a.key a.crt > server.pem
sun@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp/private$ ls
a.crt  a.key server.pem
sun@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp/private$ openssl gendh >> server.pem
Generating DH parameters, 512 bit long safe prime, generator 2
This is going to take a long time
......................++*++*++*++*++*++*
sun@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp/private$ stunnel -d 8443 -p server.pem -r localhost:8000 -f -P ''
2013.08.21 09:03:10 LOG5[5368:139785875400448]: stunnel 4.53 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
2013.08.21 09:03:10 LOG5[5368:139785875400448]: Compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
2013.08.21 09:03:10 LOG5[5368:139785875400448]: Running  with OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
2013.08.21 09:03:10 LOG5[5368:139785875400448]: Update OpenSSL shared libraries or rebuild stunnel
2013.08.21 09:03:10 LOG5[5368:139785875400448]: Threading:PTHREAD SSL:+ENGINE+OCSP Auth:LIBWRAP Sockets:POLL+IPv6
2013.08.21 09:03:10 LOG5[5368:139785875400448]: Reading configuration from descriptor 3
2013.08.21 09:03:10 LOG4[5368:139785875400448]: Insecure file permissions on server.pem
2013.08.21 09:03:10 LOG5[5368:139785875400448]: Configuration successful
```

Comment: You can always use a self signed cert.  No need to pay for one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe app engine automatically runs as Https when deployed.  Locally it is not possible to run as https.

You can however run stunnel to simulate it.

```
stunnel -d 8443 -p /path/to/ssl.pem -r localhost:8880 -f -P '' &
```

(you'll have to create the ssl.pem file) (also assume that 8880 is what port your server runs on)

Basically this will provide a proxy to your app that looks like ssl.  You'll get warning in your browser but it's good enough for local testing.

Edit:

Not really sure what's happening there. I forgot to mention that you'll need to use
  https:// local host:8443 
when connecting from the browser.

Comment: I am getting no output in browser when i am browsing https://localhost:8443 see the logs plz: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6009292/

Comment: Are you using https as the prefix?  (I ask because I've done it before)

Comment: YES - i used https as prefix but no luck, the page is not opening correctly.

Comment: Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2013-08-20 21:21:21,099 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000

looks like you are actually running on 8080 and only admin is running on 8000.  your stunnel command should probably be on 8080

Comment: YES - you are right, i did with 8080 later and still same it fails.

Comment: I wonder if "Insecure file permissions on server.pem" is causing stunnel or openSsh to balk?  you might track down that error message and see if it resolves it.

Comment: `chmod 600 server.pem` - applied and it works now!! wow!! NOTICE: if the web link is redirecting to other page like auto refresh it was failing, seems working thank you!!!!!

Comment: Great.  I remembered somewhere in the back of my head that OpenSSL gets all persnickety about "security".